# Can I convert a Google Contacts API XML response to a Gdata feed object?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-api-python-client

I'm using app engine with Oauth2 as shown here to get all contacts

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/google_app_engine

```
    if decorator.has_credentials():
    http = decorator.http()
    resp, content = http.request(decorator._scope,method="GET")
```

Here, I get the xml response for all contacts ... https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts

In the Google Contacts API V3 documentation (https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) it shows how to manipulate the data as a feed object with Gdata.

My questions is, how can I convert my `resp` to a feed object?  I'd like to know if this is possible before I start parsing the XML myself.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [GData API client library for Python](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/), which will handle all this for you.

Comment: I'll look into using this; I started with the app engine specific library because it made it very easy to get the response itself.

Comment: The Gdata lib is designed to work on top of App Engine.

Comment: I decided to change the scope to work with a JSON response which was much easier to work with, e.g. https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json